# Retaining caption and subCaption with no data in FusionCharts

Tags: charts, fusioncharts

We use many charts, and some of them simply lack data, especially when filtering for dates. In these cases, the "No data to display." message appears. That's all well and good, but the problem is that the captions and subcaptions (which we use as titles and subtitles) of the charts disappear, thereby making it difficult to identify which of the half dozen charts lack data.
example:

```
{
"chart": {
"caption": "My Caption",
"subcaption": "My Subcaption",
"plottooltext": "Document: $label<br />Total: $datavalue",
"theme": "fusion",
},
"data": []
}
```

Is there a setting we can use to still display the caption and subcatption when there is no data?

Comment: If your data array is empty FusionCharts automatically displays dataEmptyMessage on the canvas, I would suggest you isolate the caption & sub-caption from the canvas, so that you could display when there is no data - http://jsfiddle.net/rh6xsnab/

Comment: Thank you @Zapdos13 I also think this is the best solution right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at replacing the caption and subcaption with your own HTML. The captions aren't required on the charts and can be completely removed. Just make an HTML header and embed your chart below it and make sure it has no captions.